# Cant convert bytes to str implicintly in my client

Tags: python, sockets

Code

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4446

from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host,port))

msg = s.recv(1024)

print("Message From Server : " + msg)

s.close
```

I have the error as the title so I guess I dont need to right anyting more down here Please help me I am lost >_> I'm noob to sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling [`bytes.decode()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), you can get `str` object from `bytes`:

```
>>> b = b'abitrary bytes'
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> s = b.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>

>>> print(' from server ' + b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
>>> print(' from server ' + s)
 from server abitrary bytes
```

---

```
print("Message From Server : " + msg.decode('utf-8')) 
#                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can omit `'utf-8'` because it is default.

---

BTW, the last line is missing `()`:

```
s.close()
#      ^^
```